# PDF embedded in the same pane in asciidoc

Tags: pdf, asciidoc, asciidoctor, antora

I need to embed the PDF in asciidoc with all other file.
I'm able to add the pdf link but when I click on it, it opens in the new tab of the browser rather than in the same tab and within the same pane so that it would be easier to see the table of content.
Use the link to add the pdf link:https://docs.antora.org/antora/2.3/asciidoc/link-attachment/

Is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the markup that you are using, and the value of the `attachmentsdir` attribute? What does "in the same pane" mean?

Comment: I think "in the same pane" means between the "navigation" pane and the "headings" pane, where the page content is displayed. Antora would need some kind of integrated PDF viewer to do this, I am pretty sure this is not supported.